# NSFetchedResultsController's delegate method handling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController attached to it. FRC's delegate methods work perfectly and everything is nice, but my cells have custom backgrounds that depend on the position of the cell:
1. on top of the UITableView (background with rounded corners on top)
2. in the middle (background with no rounded corners)
3. on the bottom (background with rounded corners on the bottom)
4. single cell (all corners are rounded).
In my cell configuration method I calculate a position of the cell and I'm setting an appropriate background view to it. Everything works fine, but there is a problem in the implementation of FRC's delegate method:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

    UITableView *tableView =  self.agenciesTableView;

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        {

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see it is completely common, but there is one issue:
If the cell gets inserted to the top of UITableView, its configuration method (cellForRowAtIndexPath) gets called and it draws correctly (with rounded top corners) but the cell that is under it (that was previously on the top) remains with rounded top corners and I need to redraw it somehow.

-=EDITED=-

I changed FRC's delegate method to reflect the update logic:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

    UITableView *tableView =  self.agenciesTableView;

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            //if we inserting a cell not to the middle of table view
            //we need to update the previous cell (if we are inserting to the end)
            // or the next cell (if we are inserting to the beggining)
            if ([self controller:controller positionForCellAtIndexPath:newIndexPath]!=UITableViewCellPositionMiddle)
            {
                NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(newIndexPath.row+1) inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(newIndexPath.row-1) inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath])
                {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                };
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath])
                {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                };
            };
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            //if we deleting a cell not fromo the middle of table view
            //we need to update the previous cell (if we are deleting from the end)
            //or the next cell (if we are deleting from the beggining)
            if ([self controller:controller positionForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath]!=UITableViewCellPositionMiddle)
            {
                NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row+1) inSection:indexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row-1) inSection:indexPath.section];
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath])
                {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                };
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath])
                {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                };
            };
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        {

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            if ([self controller:controller positionForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath]!=UITableViewCellPositionMiddle)
            {
                NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row+1) inSection:indexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row-1) inSection:indexPath.section];
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath])
                {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                };
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath])
                {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                };
            };


            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            if ([self controller:controller positionForCellAtIndexPath:newIndexPath]!=UITableViewCellPositionMiddle)
            {
                NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(newIndexPath.row+1) inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(newIndexPath.row-1) inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath])
                {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prevIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                };
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath])
                {
                    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                };
            };
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

But in this case I'm getting an error:

```
2013-05-24 21:04:19.458 PharmaTouch[6994:fb03] *** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _computeRowUpdates], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-  1912.3/UITableViewSupport.m:386
2013-05-24 21:04:19.483 PharmaTouch[6994:fb03] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid table view update.  The application has requested an update to the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source. with userInfo (null)
```

-=EDITED2=-
here's my controller:cellExistsAtIndexPath: method implementation. It is used for safety checks to avoid reloadRowsAtIndexPaths calls with indexPath arguments that is out of bounds.

```
-(BOOL)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row<0)
    {
        return NO;
    };

    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;
    NSArray *sections = controller.sections;
    if(sections.count > 0)
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    };
    if (indexPath.row>(numberOfRows-1))
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by adding a property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates;` to keep the rows that needs to be updated between controllerWillChangeContent: controllerDidChangeContent: method calls (in FRC delegate update cycle).

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [self.agenciesTableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{

    UITableView *tableView =  self.agenciesTableView;

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        {
            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
    };
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

    UITableView *tableView =  self.agenciesTableView;

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            //if we inserting a cell not to the middle of table view
            //we need to update the previous cell (if we are inserting to the end)
            // or the next cell (if we are inserting to the beggining)
            if ([self controller:controller positionForCellAtIndexPath:newIndexPath]!=UITableViewCellPositionMiddle)
            {
                NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(newIndexPath.row-1) inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(newIndexPath.row+1) inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath])
                {
                    [self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates addObject:prevIndexPath];
                };
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath])
                {
                    [self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates addObject:nextIndexPath];
                };
            };
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            //if we deleting a cell not fromo the middle of table view
            //we need to update the previous cell (if we are deleting from the end)
            //or the next cell (if we are deleting from the beggining)
            if ([self controller:controller positionForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath]!=UITableViewCellPositionMiddle)
            {
                NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row) inSection:indexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row+1) inSection:indexPath.section];
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath])
                {
                    [self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates addObject:prevIndexPath];
                };
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath])
                {
                    [self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates addObject:nextIndexPath];
                };
            };
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            if ([self controller:controller positionForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath]!=UITableViewCellPositionMiddle)
            {
                NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row) inSection:indexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row+1) inSection:indexPath.section];
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath])
                {
                    [self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates addObject:prevIndexPath];
                };
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath])
                {
                    [self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates addObject:nextIndexPath];
                };
            };


            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            if ([self controller:controller positionForCellAtIndexPath:newIndexPath]!=UITableViewCellPositionMiddle)
            {
                NSIndexPath *prevIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(newIndexPath.row-1) inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(newIndexPath.row+1) inSection:newIndexPath.section];
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:prevIndexPath])
                {
                    [self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates addObject:prevIndexPath];
                };
                if ([self controller:controller cellExistsAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath])
                {
                    [self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates addObject:nextIndexPath];
                };
            };

            break;
        }
    };
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.agenciesTableView endUpdates];


    if ([self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates count]>0)
    {
        [self.agenciesTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[[self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates allObjects] copy] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    };
    self.indexPathsForRowsToReloadAfterFRCUpdates=nil;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` you might as well just `reloadData` and then it will be done correctly because all rows will be refreshed.

Where you're using `UITableViewRowAnimationFade`, consider how much you value it...

You'd need to be a bit more comprehensive in your checks and reloading. In particular, you need to get the section info from the FRC for the section that's changing. If the incoming or out going row is the first or last, you need to refresh more than one row. Along the lines of:

```
if first is changing and count > 1, also refresh second
if last is changing and count > 1, also refresh first
```

Comment: What is cellExistsAtIndexPath:?

Comment: I've added this cellExistsAtIndexPath: implementation

Comment: You'll need to do a bit of debugging. It's probably something to do with ordering and you should probably wrap the changes in beginUpdates - endUpdates.